# Strange case error of java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 47

Tags: java, android, jsonreader

I have 2 same projects that has same task, it is want to access web service from android with JsonReader,

**project 1** was running well and everything good there is no problem, 
**project 2** was appearing the exception ===> "com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 47"

for make sure I even copy and paste it class that call JsonReader from proj1 to proj2 can anyone help me to fix it. this is the class I called from Asyntasks `

```
public <T> T Gets(String url, List<NameValuePair> params, final Type t) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;// getNewHttpconnection();
        // String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
        if(params != null) {
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
        }


        try {
            URL urls = new URL(url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) urls.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
            connection.setReadTimeout(60000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
            connection.connect();


            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                Log.e("asds", "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage());
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                String contentEncoding = connection.getContentEncoding();
                if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                    inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
                }
                JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
                 reader.setLenient(true);
                System.out.print(reader);
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                T temp =  gson.fromJson(reader, t);
                //     tem = temp;
                inputStream.available();
                inputStream.close();
                return  temp;
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        return null;
    }`
```

Comment: Not strange, you passed a JSON array.

Comment: This issue is in JSON. you passed json object but require jsonarray

Comment: your `Type t` model does not match JSON to be deserialized.

Comment: My Model from webservice look like :